# How to set size of two dimensional ArrayList?

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make an two dimensional ArrayList which has a set amount of ArrayLists, then each of those ArrayLists can contain as much as needed. I'm aware that arrays dynamically change size, but I'm trying to guarantee that is has at least a certain size in this case.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> integers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(10);
```

This doesn't work. I want to be able to set the location of a new Integer to one of the first dimension's indices, like so:

```
integers.get(7).add(new Integer(42));
```

This just gives me an IndexOutOfBoundsException, as though there are no Integer ArrayLists within the ArrayList. Is there a way to do this? I'm sure it's something simple I'm not seeing.

Comment: You are going to have to create the `ArrayList` and use a value that's not a value that will be common in the `ArrayList`. Let's say all of your Integers a positive, then you can use something like -1. I personally think you should use `Array`s. `ArrayList` are not designed to do this. `Array`s are perfect for this

Comment: Also`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> integers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();` This is hedious. You should do this instead `List<List<Integer>> integers = new ArrayList();`.

Answer (score 3):

Array *lists* do not work like this. They are not arrays.

The list you created is backed by array of at least 10 elements, but itself it does not contain any, so you cannot refer to 7th or actually any one element.

```
integers.size() would return 0
integers.isEmpty() would return true
integers.get(0) would throw
```

Moreover, the list you initialized needs to be filled with lists themselves:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  row = new ArrayList<Integer>()
  integers.add(row);
}
// now integers is a 10-element list of empty lists
```

Alternatively you could use primitive arrays (if you want to have a fixed-size rectangle).

```
int integers[][] = new int[10][];
for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; ++i) {
   integers[i] = new int[10]; // rows are initialized to 0, as int is primitive
}
for (final int[] arr : integers) {
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested loop for this. Here is a short example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PopulateArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> integers = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        int num_arrays_ to_populate = 10;
        int num_indices_to_populate = 10;

        for(int i = 0; i < num_arrays_to_populate; i++) {
            integers.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
            for(int j = 0; j < num_indices_to_populate; j++) {

                integers.get(i).add(0);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This would create an ArrayList of ArrayLists of ints and fill the top ArrayList with 10 ArrayLists and put a 0 in the first 10 cells of each. Obviously you can change any of those numbers to do what you want.

Note/Disclaimer: I wrote this on my phone, so if I missed a brace or semicolon, just comment and I’ll add it. The logic is there, though.